# How to extend an existing (Gutenberg) block

Tags: media, block-editor

One of my Wordpress sites has a custom field for media which contains the credit for the media item. (Something like "Photo by John Doe".)

Before Gutenberg, I overwrote the default shortcode which displayed the image, to include the credit when displaying the image in the frontend. But, with Gutenberg blocks, this no longer works.

I could create a custom block from scratch which essentially would duplicate the image block, adding the credit, but this would mean a lot of unnecessary, duplicate, work.

Preferably, I somehow adjust the default's block behaviour to add some HTML to the output of the block (which will include the credit) and to insert the credit into the block.

Is this possible? How? Where do I find a resource on how to extend existing blocks?

Alternatively, from where can I copy the code of the existing image block to create my own block, based on this existing block?

Comment: Unfortunately I think this isn't possible yet. React generally favours embedding components within new components to extend them, rather than subclassing them. The WordPress core blocks are not components, so extending in this way is not possible. I hope in the future the WordPress developers move more of their core block code into components that can be imported and reused in other blocks.

Comment: Thanks. I did find a piece on extending a block, but this only changes the display. Ex: https://jeffreycarandang.com/extending-gutenberg-core-blocks-with-custom-attributes-and-controls/. I suppose I could build some ajax functionality around this to load a credit, but that seems convoluted.

Comment: Alternatively, can I just 'lift' the code for the image block from somewhere, duplicate the code and then adjust that? Where's the code for the default blocks?

Comment: Yes you can; the code is [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-library). There's another snag though: the core blocks are being regularly updated as the developers add features. You may find your copied code quickly becomes out of date. It's a little messy right now since it's all so new. I hope in the future the image block functionality (and other useful core block functionality) can be embedded as a component in other blocks (I added [an issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/18548) for this too).

Comment: It seems that you could use the `blocks.getSaveElement` and `editor.BlockEdit` filters modify the markup of an existing block.